# Understand return statement in request interceptor of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

We are all using interceptors for our applications. But since i used it, i don't understand the retunr statement of the request & response method inside the interceptor :

> return config || $q.when(config);

As i understand it, if the config object is undefined the method will return the config wrap in the when method of promise API because we don't know if it's a promise or not. That's ok i think.

But my question is how is it possible to get an undefined config Object in a request ?

Thx for your replies

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think the public API allows you to pass in a falsy config. You can call `$http(null)` but this will throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null`.

But then I don't understand the purpose of the `|| when` either. If `$q.when(config)` is called, you know `config` is falsy. So the interceptor returns a promise that resolves to `null`, for example. Why not just return `null` ?

Comment: I understand you but don't blame me, your question is my question !! This code is in the angularjs documentation about interceptors !!!!

Comment: I don't blame you, I think it is an interesting question. I posted this as an answer because it answers "But my question is how is it possible to get an undefined config Object in a request ?". But that still leaves open some other questions ...

Comment: FYI, this is the commit https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4ae46814ff4e7c0bbcdbbefc0a97277283a84065 and this is the PR, I think: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2130

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The function is free to modify the config or create a new one. The function needs to return the config directly or as a promise

If interceptor 1 returns `undefined`, then interceptor 2 would get an undefined config.

But that doesn't explain the statement, because we still wouldn't have a **valid** config (with headers etc.). So it's not meant as "real" code but is rather the statement from the docs:

> return the config directly = **return config** or as a promise = **|| $q.when(config)**

Comment: So we never get undefined ... This statement is useless ! Any explanation ! The AngularJS team write code everyone write the same and nobody understand it ! it's amazing lol